# Check which (multiple) cells in column A contain substrings specified in column B?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

In column A I have M&A deal descriptions that mention company names. In column B I have company names, for each of which I want to see where it is mentioned in column A.

What I'm having trouble with: Some of the strings in column B will be present as substrings in column A multiple times and I want to return all of the instances, not just one.

Comment: Perhaps a small example, e.g. 10 or so lines, together with expected results would be of benefit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS excel - assigning "categories" based on keywords](http://superuser.com/questions/785128/ms-excel-assigning-categories-based-on-keywords)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rather small macro:

```
Sub DataLocator()
  Dim nA As Long, nB As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  Dim v As String
  nA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  nB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 1 To nB
    v = Cells(i, "B").Value
    k = 3
    For j = 1 To nA
      If InStr(1, Cells(j, "A").Value, v) > 0 Then
        Cells(i, k).Value = Cells(j, "A").Address(0, 0)
        k = k + 1
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**