# Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

The formula in Microsoft Excel is not any different than in the Google Sheets. But, I get different results

[image: left Microsoft Excel, right Google Sheets]
      (left) Microsoft Excel,              (right) Google Sheets

The Google Excel formula works;
the same Google Sheets formula does not work in the Microsoft Excel one.

How can I fix this? Ignore the Dutch separator `;` –
in the English version with the separator `,` I have the same problem.

Comment: Is your question ultimately *how do I get this formula to work in Microsoft Excel*?  If so, please edit your question to clarify that. In particular asking *Is it Google Excel?* makes it unclear which question you're asking.

Comment: Good edit. This is a lot more focused. However, in which is the formula correct (Google Sheets or MS Excel?)

Comment: Why will someone give my question a minus 1?

Comment: @Twisty: The question says, “left Microsoft Excel, right Google Sheets” / “The Google Excel formula works, the same … formula does not work in the Microsoft Excel one.” Also, the Google Sheet (the one on the right) is showing intelligible results in Column `D`, where the Excel worksheet (the one on the left) is showing “other” in every row.

Comment: @G-Man I asked my clarifying questions *before* the OP edited his answer in response to them.

Comment: @decibel :I didn’t down vote you, but I am unhappy that (1) you [posted an image of data without posting it in textual form](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/80216) (see [here](http://superuser.com/q/889201/354511) and [here](http://superuser.com/q/892744/354511) for examples of how to do it), and (2) you’re asking for help on a formula with five function calls without explaining what it’s supposed to do. Other people probably feel similarly.

Comment: If the objective is to get the desired functionality working in Excel, this is a possible duplicate of [MS Excel – assigning “categories” based on keywords](http://superuser.com/questions/785128/ms-excel-assigning-categories-based-on-keywords)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem on the Excel side is
that you seem to be expecting `SEARCH(range, value)`
to return an array, but, as far as I can tell from the question,
you have not entered it as an *array formula*. 
If you click in cell `D2`
and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>,
your formula will work.

Comment: I think that to perform an array formula in Google Sheets, you need to preface the formula with =(ArrayFormula( instead of the button combo above.

Comment: @O.Allen:  Well, I don’t know much about Google Sheets, so I won’t dispute what you’re saying — except to point out that, in the image in the question, it appears that `SEARCH(F$2:F$5, A2)` is returning an array (like ```{10, #VALUE, #VALUE, #VALUE}```) in Google Sheets without using `ArrayFormula`.