# Excel Formula CONTAINS

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I need a formula that will look for a specific text in a cell that is also referenced on another sheet and input the value next to it. Kind of like a vlookup but with an if statement. "if text contains value in this other cell, put the corresponding value"

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: A specific example would be helpful

Comment: Thanks Albin. Sheet 1 has a list of text fields and a corresponding value next to them: Apple | Green, Cherry | Red, Cucumber | Green, Carrot | Orange.... and Sheet 2 has a cell with a description "The Apple fell from the tree and dropped to the ground", then I would like the cell to return with value "GREEN"

Comment: that is not very specific, try adding a screenshot or s.th. similar, and explain the example in the screenshot

Comment: I hit enter too fast. Does the above now help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS excel - assigning "categories" based on keywords](https://superuser.com/questions/785128/ms-excel-assigning-categories-based-on-keywords)

Comment: @Tiffany did you solve your problem with the existing answers? If you did, please accept the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/FIND($A$2:$A$5,E2),$B$2:$B$5),"")
```

[image]

Comment: An explanation of how/why this works would make it a more educational answer.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this Formula also:**

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A2, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5)), MATCH(ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5), ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5))), ROWS($A$1:A$1)))
```

[image]

**Note,**

- Write this Formula in Cell `B2` of `Sheet 2` & fill it Down.
- You can adjust Sheet name & Cell references in the formula as needed.