# Extract Text String within Cell, compare with list and return value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a string of text containing item names and artist titles etc.

I also have a seperate list of artist names.

I am trying to find out how to search the cell to match text from within the list, and then return the specific matched text.

As the data is from different sources the formats are different so splitting cells is messy, and I can only seem to return True or False or a specific set text.

As I need to understand what has been matched, how can I return that value?

Many thanks.

Comment: some sample data and a demonstration of what you have tried so far would go a long way.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried every search I could find on Google and got stuck as I am still learning the more advanced formulas. I apologise for not showing more details. I spent 9 hours banging my head before I posted this as my first question. I am not entirely sure how to share samle data as I am new to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With phrases in column **A** and artists names in column **C** from **C1** through **C6**, in **B1** enter the *Array Formula*:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$6,A1)),$C$1:$C$6,""))
```

and copy downward.  For example:

[image]

As you see, the artist name is extracted.  If there is more than one name in the phrase, then all are extracted.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

NOTE:

You can adapt this to your own data schema.

Comment: Great thank you so much. This looks like it should do the trick. I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: You should have answered [Excel - find text within a string and return that text](https://superuser.com/q/1434625/364367).  :-)  I'm going to propose making that a duplicate of this one since this is the best solution.

Comment: @fixer1234  I like this solution since it can return more than one match.

Comment: @fixer1234 - I have notification to say that the question has been put on hold as its unclear what I am asking. Gary's Student has answered it perfectly as thats exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @ShadowFingers, yeah, this is a great solution, and Gary's Student correctly interpreted your question. The reason the question got put on hold is that it's ambiguous, which limits people's ability to answer and its value to other people with a similar problem.  If you can add a screenshot to the question illustrating the problem, that would go a long way to making it clearer (stick the image at a public sharing site like imgur.com and post a link to it).  Include a mockup of what the results should look like for those examples.  With that improvement, we should be able to reopen the question.